# Change select option of Dropdown in ajax request in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a data table which is firing an ajax request.

`addOnloadEvent(function () {`

```
var oTable = $('#lenderList').dataTable(                         
    {                                                            
        bServerSide: true,                                       
        bProcessing: true,                                       
        sAjaxSource: "loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val(),                
        sServerMethod: 'POST',                                   
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          "ajax": {                                              
              "data": function ( d ) {                           
                  d.extra_search = $('#category').val();         
              }                                                  
          },                                                     

        aoColumns: [                                             
            {                                                    
                "sName": "loanApplicationNumber",                
                mData: "loanApplicationNumber"                   
            },                                                   
            {                                                    
                "sName": "name",                                 
                mData: "name"                                    
            },                                                   
            {                                                    
                "sName": "submissionDate",                       
                mData: "submissionDate"                          
            },                                                   
            {                                                    
                "sName": "kycEmailId",                           
                mData: "kycEmailId"                              
            }                                               
        ],                                                       
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',                               
        "tableTools": {                                          
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"              
        }                                                        
    }                                                            
);
```

In the ajax call, it takes the category value(Which is a dropdown)

`sAjaxSource: "loanAdminAjax?ajax=true&searchCol="+$('#category').val(),`

```
 <select name="category"  id="category">                                     
    <option  value="loanApplicationNumber">loanApplicationNumber</option>   
    <option value="name">name</option>                                      
    <option value="kyc_email">EmailId</option>                              
    <option value="documentStatus">documentStatus</option>                  
</select>
```

I want to change the category value which is sent in the ajax request whenever someone selects a new value. Could someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understood, the ajax call must be done each time the user changes the selected option.

So here you need an event listener for each time the selected item changes in select:

```
$('#category').on('change', function() {
  // Here you put all the ajax call
});
```

Comment: I have to update the data table ajax request dynamically which is taking the static value that is the value of the dropdown at the begining. I have tried such solutions but the changed value is not getting updated in the data table ajax requeste